# Set stack address for each function

Tags: c, stack

For a special memory management software, I want to specify the beginning address of each function's stack. Its functionality should be quite similar to `pthread_attr_setstackaddr`, but instead of set the stack address of each thread, I want to set the stack address of each function. For example, is there function/way I can set the stack addresses like:

```
SetFuncStack(main);
int main(){
  int a = 0;
  SetFuncStack(func1);
  func1();
  int b = 10;
  SetFuncStack(func2);
  func2();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

UPDATE:
So I'm open to any possible techniques, e.g., I'm ok if I have to change the compiler or some kernel code. I'm just not sure how should I do it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. The stack is simply pushed from where it currently is.

Comment: You can do it for threads because creating a new thread involves creating a new stack for it, and that can be located anywhere. But you can't change the location of the stack for a thread after it's already running.

Comment: I mean, you can absolutely do this by simply writing your own C compiler, or customizing an existing one. Otherwise you're probably out of luck. You could write a wrapper function that alters the stack, then calls the function passed as an argument, and then repairs the stack - but you'd have to do it in assembly. And you wouldn't be able to pass function arguments on the stack ...

Comment: Maybe someone can come up with a suggestion if you provide a bigger context of what you are trying to do

Comment: In theory, all you have to do is push a stack frame of such a size that the new stack pointer will be at the target location (which I presume is mapped and reserved for this use), even if that size is “negative” and wraps around memory. So may be possible to do it with standard code for the ABI you are using. (Standard assembly code for pushing a stack frame that is, not C code.)

Comment: That totally precludes recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is possible. For CPU scheduling we use the `ucontext.h` library which gives you access to a context block to store the function, stack, and other things. You should maintain a RunQ of context blocks. To add to the RunQ, call `allocate_context(function);` with:

```
void allocate_context(void (*function) (void)){
    ucontext_t* context = (ucontext_t*)malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t)); //allocate a context block
    int* stack = malloc(8192); //allocate a stack of 8192 bytes
    init_Context(Context, function, stack, sizeof(stack)); //call init_TCB
    AddQueue(RunQ, TCB); //call addQ to add this TCB into the "RunQ" 
}

    void init_Context (ucontext_t context, void (*function) (void), void *stackP, int stack_size){
    memset(context, '\0', sizeof(ucontext_t)); // wash, rinse
    getcontext(context); //get parent context
    context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP; 
    context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t) stack_size;
    makecontext(context, function, 0); // context is now cooked
}
```